# What are Vectors in programming (LibGDX)?

Tags: java, libgdx

I've seen vectors quite a bit in my time learning LibGDX and coding in general. But I've never been able to grasp what they are.

I know:

- In other programming languages they are a (depreciated) way of dealing with array lists.
- In physics, they represent magnitude and direction.

In programming, do they also represent magnitude and direction? Is the array aspect to say that they represent all points between two x and y coordinates?

Or else do they represent a single point that has a direction, ie when that point moves it will go in that direction? Does it signify movement?

Example:

```
BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
bodyDef.position.set(new Vector2(Constants.GROUND_X, Constants.GROUND_Y));
```

What is happening here? Why would we want to set the ground to a vector?

Comment: It depends on the context. In game development,  think vector is more associated with physics. In general programming language, a vector may be a 1 dimension array, like in maths.

Comment: https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html  
You should probably review the tutorials for the library in question. Your example code creates a body and sets its position (which is described by a 2d vector) to whatever the 'ground' constants are.

Answer (score 3):

> `std::vector`, `Vector2` and `Vector3` and `vector math`

- [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), is a sequence container in c++ that encapsulates dynamic size arrays.
- [Vector2](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html) and [Vector3](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector3.html) are classes in Libgdx API that contains 2 and 3 float value respectively also having number of method that help in practical implementation of vector math.
- vector math is an amazing tool that makes programming of complex behaviors much simpler. vector math is very helpful in 2D/3D game development.

  **vector as magnitude and direction**

  Typically, we define coordinates as an (x,y) pair, x representing the horizontal offset and y the vertical one. This makes sense given the screen is just a rectangle in two dimensions. As an example, here is a position in 2D space:

  [image]

  A position can be anywhere in space. The position (0,0) has a name, it’s called the **origin**. Remember this term well because it has more implicit uses later. The (0,0) of a n-dimensions coordinate system is the **origin**.

  In vector math, coordinates have two different uses, both equally important. They are used to represent a position but also a vector. The same position as before, when imagined as a vector, has a different meaning.

  [image]

  When imagined as a vector, two properties can be inferred, the direction and the magnitude. Every position in space can be a vector, with the exception of the origin. This is because coordinates (0,0) can’t represent direction (magnitude 0).

  [image]

---

Comment: This is helpful. So the vector is the point, not the line? And the direction of the vector is determined by its relation to the origin?

Comment: **vector is not line**. In cartesian coordinate system that is a point and in polar coordinate system that treat as magnitude and direction.